# How can I solve showDatePicker area in flutter (The method 'formatFullDate' was called on null.)

Tags: flutter, dart

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Directionality(textDirection: ltr): The method 'formatFullDate' was called on null.

```
RaisedButton.icon(
  icon: Icon(Icons.date_range),
  label: Text('Start'),
  onPressed: () async {
    var date = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      locale: Locale.fromSubtags(
        countryCode: 'KE',
        languageCode: 'EN',
      ),
      firstDate: DateTime(2008),
      useRootNavigator: true,
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
      builder: (context, widget) => widget,
    );
    print(date);
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized the localizations are wrong. Fixed it by

```
locale: Locale.fromSubtags(
          countryCode: 'en',
          languageCode: 'US',
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
locale: Locale.fromSubtags(
  countryCode: 'KE',
  languageCode: 'en',
),
```